# Test LINQ to SQL expression

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-expressions

I am writing an application that works with MS SQL database via LINQ to SQL. I need to perform filtering sometimes, and occasionally my filtering conditions are too complicated to be translated into SQL query. While I am trying to make them translatable, I want my application to at least work, though slow sometimes.

LINQ to SQL data model is hidden inside repositories, and I do not want to provide several GetAll method overloads for different cases and be aware of what overload to use on upper levels. So I want to test my expression inside repository to be translatable and, if no, perform in-memory query against the whole data set instead of throwing NotSupportedException on query instantiating.

This is what I have now:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> table = GetTable<TEntity>();
IQueryable<TEntity> result;
try
{
    result = table.Where(searchExpression);

    //this will test our expression 
    //consuming as little resources as possible (???)        
    result.FirstOrDefault(); 
}
catch (NotSupportedException)
{
    //trying to perform in-memory search if query could not be constructed
    result = table
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(searchExpression.Compile())
        .AsQueryable();
}
return result;
```

`searchExpression` is `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`

As you see, I am using `FirstOrDefault` to try to instantiate the query and throw the exception if it cannot be instantiated. However, it will perform useless database call when the expression is good. I could use `Any`, `Count` or other method, and it may well be a bit less expensive then `FirstOrDefault`, but still all methods that come to my mind make a costly trip to database, while all I need is to test my expression.

Is there any alternative way to say whether my expression is 'good' or 'bad', without actual database call?

**UPDATE:**

Or, more generally, is there a way to tell LINQ to make in-memory queries when it fails to construct SQL, so that this testing mechanism would not be needed at all?

Comment: I think you have a design flaw here: Your repository should not return `IQueryable` but only collections that are decoupled from the database. When you do this, your problem won't exist anymore.

Comment: What don't you see? Why it makes your problems go away or why it is a design flaw?

Comment: Why it makes my problems go away. I may agree that returning `IQueryable` to consumers may be a flaw, as then they'll be able to run arbitrary queries with uncontrolled untranslatable expressions, which would cause unexpected run-time errors. But what I want is to be able to run arbitrary query **INSIDE** my repository. Method signature looks like that: `GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> searchExpression)`, and I need guarantee that whoever calls it and whatever legal expression is passed to it, it returns the filtered collection of items, at least in-memory one.

Comment: About the flaw: Yes, that's what I meant. About your problem going away: I somehow missed that the `searchExpression` will only be evaluated for one table. Can you please give me an example of a `searchExpression` that is not supported? I assume this happens, when user defined methods are used?

Comment: User defined methods, properties defined in partial class and the stuff like that. The idea is not to try to "SQLize" every single expression - there are already tons of them, and I am actually SQLizing them now - but to guarantee that the collection is returned. SQLization could take weeks of time, but the site needs to be up and running now. We can afford slowness in some areas, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
   result.FirstOrDefault();
```

would it be sufficient to use

```
    string sqlCommand = dataContext.GetCommand(result).CommandText;
```

?

If the expression does not generate valid Sql, this should throw a NotSupportedException, but it does not actually execute the sqlCommand.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> table = GetTable<TEntity>();  
IQueryable<TEntity> result;
try
{
    return table.Where(searchExpression).ToList();
}
catch (NotSupportedException)
{
    //trying to perform in-memory search if query could not be constructed
    return table
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(searchExpression.Compile())
        .ToList();
}
```

So the method returns is the expression is converted to valid SQL. Otherwise it catches the exception and runs the query in memory. This should work but it doesn't answer your question if it's possible to check if a specific `searchExpression` can be converted. I don't think such a thing exists.

Comment: This will also instantiate the query, and I do not want this to happen that early. What if I finally just count the items? Or check if there is any? I would still have the whole data set fetched from SQL server. Your approach is basically the same as my `FirstOrDefault()`: instantiate the query right in the repository and catch the instantiation exception. Mine is better, though, cause it does not fetch the whole  data set, but only the first record. Using `Any()` may be even better, as it will fetch only true/false from the SQL server, not the whole structure.

Comment: @Michael: If your Expression can't be translated to SQL there won't be any database hit. So, if `searchExpression` can't be converted to SQL, the part inside the `try` block will throw an exception without hitting the database. In any case, you will have only one database hit.